# Image goes out of container in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I'm using "publisher theme" with visual composer (WPBakery Page Builder)

After I updated the theme, all images are showing full size and going out of the right hand side of the columns.

It is visible on all pages as all pages contain some wide images that use to be "responsive" the column width.

This is the [domain](http://ampmdoorservices.ca/).

Thanks in Advance!

Simon

Comment: put     img{max-width:100%;height:auto}  in your style.css file

Comment: worked!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!!!!!